# email validation on create an account page

Tags: email, magento-1.9, form-validation

I want my "create an account" form to only accept .gov emails. If the user doesn't have a .gov email, they cannot create an account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the prototype validations to create a custom one. 
Code:

> Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid Gmail address. For example johndoe@gmail.com.', function(v) {
>       return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@gmail.com)$/i.test(v)
>   })

Guide [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/).

Comment: Awesome guide! Thank you for the quick response! :-)